# How to execute the Unix commands saved in text file on putty using batch file

Tags: linux, unix, batch-file, automation, putty

wants to execute the Unix commands saved in text file from batch file using putty.

I've created a `.bat` file with this line:

```
start C:\Users\putty.exe -load "server" -l userID -pw Password -m commands.txt
```

and `commands.txt` file contained Unix command

```
ls
```

I got the success to logged-in in my account through putty But the command `ls` added in text is not executed

Assuming there is no need to use plink.exe since i can logged-in with putty.exe itself

Comment: no error msgs? Good test case, but maybe try `/bin/ls` or `echo inside test script`? Good luck.

Comment: yes, no error message. also tried with tail -5000 /bin/abc/| grep 'keyword'  .  But my concern is tail command not even get written  on putty command window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its getting executed, its just you are not able to see it, it disappers before you can note anything

to be sure just change your command.txt content from

```
ls
```

to

```
ls >file_ls
```

and then check the file 'file_ls' in your home directory on "server" It will have ls output.